# Select rows within a date range in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, date

I have a set of rows, each with a date value, and I need to select rows that fall within a specific date range. How can I do this?

```
select * from table where convert(int,date_created) between //what should go here?
```

I want to select between `'20-10-2010'`  and `'22-10-2010'`.

It keeps complaining about string to date conversion.

Comment: ``date_created`` is a DATETIME field, so I was trying to delete the time bit by converting it to int? someone told me that's how its done, sorry I might be confused!

Comment: possible duplicate of [datetime in where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947436/datetime-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use yyyymmdd which is the safest format for SQL Server

```
select * from table
where date_created BETWEEN '20101020' and '20101022'
```

Not sure why you had CONVERT to int there...

Note: if date_created has a time component that this fails because it assume midnight.

Edit:

To filter for the day 20 Oct 2010 to 22 Oct 2010 *inclusive*, if the `date_created` column has times, without applying a function to `date_created`:

```
where date_created >= '20101020' and date_created < '20101023'
```

Comment: okay that was easy. thanks. Also, my date_created is DATETIME. should I be worried about that?

Comment: sorry, one more question, does between clause include the boundary dates?

Comment: @LocustHorde: 1. between is inclusive 2. do you have times in your datetime values?

Comment: Hi, so how do I deal with datetime? I used int convert so i can chuck the time bit?

Comment: @LocustHorde: You can use this `select cast(floor(cast(date_created as float)) as datetime)` to remove the time portion if needed.

Comment: @LocustHorde, @Barry: changing the condition removes the need to have a function on date_created which will invalidate any index usage. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/133081/27535 anyway

Answer (score 2):

Either don't convert the `date_created` to an `int` or use integers for your data values

I would leave the `date_created` as a date.

`select * from table 
where date_created between '20101020' and '20101022'`

Comment: whilst I agree with the sentiment, this isn't really an answer to the question