# How to write sql query to get the datetime from one date to another date?

Tags: sql

How to write sql query to get the datetime from one date to another date?
 example : from 21-06-14 00:00:00 am to 24-06-14 11:59:59 am

Can any one please help?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Can you provide an example of what you expect as output, and show us what you've tried that didn't work for you.

Comment: to_char(datecol,'dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss)+11/12

Comment: how to get date with time as 11:59:59 am?

Comment: ..you want to get the date, then set the time to 11:59:59 am?

Comment: date along with time as 11:59:59?

Comment: like (sysdate,'dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss)+11/12..

Answer (score 0):

Use following,

SELECT *
FROM `your table name`
WHERE `tablefieldName` BETWEEN '2014-06-21 00:00:00'
                          AND '2014-06-24 23:59:59'

Please see below,
[Datetime in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947436/datetime-in-where-clause)