# MS Access / Excel SQL Server query producing Conversion error DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, vba

I've looked around for a solution for this, but none of them seem to fix my problem

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Appointment_Date]
FROM dbo.RF_Performance_Referrals_Main
WHERE (([Appointment_Date]) < '7/21/2014')
ORDER BY [Appointment_Date] DESC
```

Above is the Simplified version of the query I am trying to. I keep get an error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Then Conversion of a
>   varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range
>   value

I thought maybe there is a problem with my connection...

so I tried it on Excel and got the exact same error...

I checked the SQL Server table that particular field is set to DATETIME

So why is it giving an error?

I tried all sorts of stuff on Cast/Convert, but none of them seem to work i still get the same error. I don't really get why.

Please help if fix this.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: have you tried using a date time?  '7/21/2014 00:00:00' and what local is on the sever? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947436/datetime-in-where-clause

Comment: or it could be: http://www.sqltrainingonline.com/sql-date-comparison-how-to-filter-datetime-in-sql-server/

Comment: `code`SELECT TOP 10 [Appointment_Date]
FROM dbo.RF_Performance_Referrals_Main
WHERE ([Appointment_Date] < '7/21/2014 00:00:00')
ORDER BY [Appointment_Date] DESC

Tried what you said... Same Error.. it used to work brilliantly till someone higher up decided they wanted to merge prev & future appointments.

I am going to try reading through the second link. This problem is really affecting the department we can't see who requires and urgent appointment >_< and the Information Team that made this table don't have a clue why either it's been 3-4 weeks they are still trying to sort it out T_T

Comment: Nevermind.. Think it's working don't understand why, but it does not like any other date format except '2014-21-7'

Thanks a lot -- Would you like to post that so that I can accept your answer ... it was the second link that got me trying '2014-21-7'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server's default date time syntax is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS as in (1900-01-01 00:00:00)

You either have to cast your string to a date or reformat your input to the expected datetime defaults: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx:  Assuming US Local and standard defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Appointment_Date]
FROM dbo.RF_Performance_Referrals_Main
WHERE (([Appointment_Date]) < #2014/07/21#)
ORDER BY [Appointment_Date] DESC
```