# How can i get Date from Yesterday on my Chart with a Button?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I made a chart from my SQL table, it shows the temperature of my raspis. Now I try to show the temperature data from a certain time with a button such as Button1 shows the temperature 1 day ago. Someone knows how exactly it can do it or show me the code?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="TablePL" runat="server">
            <div align="center">
          <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Sql_Data_Source" OnLoad="Chart1_Load1" Width="1700px" Height="400px">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Temperatur" XValueMember="Date" YValueMembers="SensorValueDbl" ChartType="Line" Legend="Legend1" XValueType="DateTime" BorderWidth="3">
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        <AxisY LineWidth="2">
                        </AxisY>
                        <AxisX Interval="1" IsLabelAutoFit="False" LineWidth="2" Crossing="Max" IntervalType="Days" IsMarginVisible="False">
                            <StripLines>
                                <asp:StripLine />
                            </StripLines>
                            <LabelStyle Angle="-90" Font="Arial, 9pt" Interval="Auto" IntervalType="Auto" />
                        </AxisX>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
                <Legends>
                    <asp:Legend Name="Legend1" Docking="Top">
                    </asp:Legend>
                </Legends>
                <Titles>
                    <asp:Title Name="RASPBERRY PI TEMPERATUR" Text="RASPBERRY PI TEMPERATUR" Font="Arial Narrow, 18pt">
                    </asp:Title>
                </Titles>
            </asp:Chart>
                </div>

            <center>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="return valdateTemp();" runat="server" Text="1 Day" value="1d" />
            </center>     
</form>
```

Here I get my Data from SQL:

```
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionsStringDB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT [ID],[SensorValueDbl] FROM[TemperaturDB].[dbo].[T_Sensorvalues]";
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            
            TablePL.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = sb.ToString() });
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Chart1_Load1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

And here is my table:

[image]

Comment: We don't know your DB Table Schema, but it probably would be a [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause, filtering for a date...

Comment: I updated with a image

Comment: What column type is that `[Date]`Column? varchar? datetime2 ?

Comment: @Fildor datetime

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1947469/982149

Comment: I mean like this but without canvas and Javscript : https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/zxrkh502/

Comment: So is this about the _query_ of the data or the UI Element to render a graph?